# Missing number, treated as zero: in enumerate (polyglossia and Xepersian)

Tags: enumerate

I'm using the packages `polyglossia` and `Xepersian`, I have a problem with third level enumerate, I cannot use `\Alph` numbering in the whole document,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[nonamebreak, square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[calendar=gregorian, numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5]{Amiri}
\setotherlanguage{english}


\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Amiri}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.5]{Amiri}



\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
  \let\endoldthebibliography=\endthebibliography
  \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \begin{oldthebibliography}{#1}%
      \setlength{\parskip}{2ex}%vertical space between items
        }%
  {%
    \end{oldthebibliography}%
  }

\begin{document}

 كز هنا في الحديث على  نظام زي‌تك لأنه أحد أفضل الحلول المتاحة  \citep{ماجدة2012تطوير}
 نفترض هنا وجود معرفة مسبقة
 \cite{kopka2004guide}
 \begin{enumerate}
\item Test one
\item Test two
\begin{enumerate}%problem
\item Test one one
\item Test two two
\end{enumerate}%problem
\item Test three
\item Test four
\end{enumerate}

\bibliographystyle{asa-fa}

\bibliography{MyReferences}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why use of `polyglossia` with `xepersian` together, one is enough.

Comment: What do you mean with `Alph`  in arabic script

Comment: I struggled long time to solve the problem of using References Arabic (RTL) and English (LTR) simultaneously, the only solution that i found is Xepersian with \Natbib package.

Comment: What i mean by `\Alph`  is: in my document it is impossible to use `\Alph` numbering whether for `\subfigure`  or Third level list etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a slight modification to your MWE it will solve the error. i.e. change:

```
\setmainlanguage[calendar=gregorian, numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
```

to

```
\selectlanguage[calendar=gregorian, numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
```

This will solve the problem. Hence the updated MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[nonamebreak, square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\selectlanguage[calendar=gregorian, numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
%\setmainlanguage[calendar=gregorian, numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5]{Amiri}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\TOCLanguage{arabic}


\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Amiri}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.5]{Amiri}


\let\oldthebibliography=\thebibliography
\let\endoldthebibliography=\endthebibliography
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
\begin{oldthebibliography}{#1}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{2ex}%vertical space between items
    }%
{%
\end{oldthebibliography}%
}

\begin{document}

 كز هنا في الحديث على  نظام زي‌تك لأنه أحد أفضل الحلول المتاحة  \citep{ماجدة2012تطوير}
 نفترض هنا وجود معرفة مسبقة
 \cite{kopka2004guide}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test one
\item Test two
\begin{enumerate}%problem
\item Test one one
\item Test two two
\end{enumerate}%problem
\item Test three
\item Test four
\end{enumerate}

\bibliographystyle{asa-fa}

\bibliography{MyReferences}

\end{document}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Jagath, this solution does not  work, i get the error **! You can't use `\setlanguage' in vertical mode.**

Comment: Oops! A typo. Could you please change setlanguage to selectlanguage.

Comment: Thank you @Jagath, this option changes the main language of the document from Arabic to Persian e.g. default `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures`, `\today` and `\listoftables`  ...

Comment: @AbdoElfengour: Sorry. I am not familiar with these languages. Could you please put this `\TOCLanguage{arabic}` in preamble after loading the package.